# Spliting and reading from string in Java

Tags: java, string

I've written a code that works similar to calculator, but it solves cryptarithmetic equations. It works fine with basic operations like +-*/.
Now I added the power and root operation and it doesn't work when I use those two new operations. It seems that the problem is with the way I split the input string. The problem is that it doesn't split the string with "^" operator. Here is the code where the problem occurs:

```
private void findOperator() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] tempString = this.rawInputString.split("");
    for(String s : tempString){
        if(s.equals("+")){
            this.operator = "[+]";
            break;
        }
        else if(s.equals("*")){
            this.operator = "[*]";
            break;
        }
        else if(s.equals("-")){
            this.operator = s;
            break;
        }
        else if(s.equals("/")){
            this.operator = s;
            break;
        }
        else if(s.equals("^")){
            this.operator = s;
            break;
        }
        else if(s.equals("sqrt")){
            this.operator = s;
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void parseInput(){

    String[] tempString = rawInputString.split(this.operator);
    this.firstString = tempString[0].split("");
    this.firstLetterFirstNumber = this.firstString[0];
    String temporarySecondPart = tempString[1];//This is where it says I
                                    //have the problem, but it works fine  
                                   //with other operators              
    this.operator = rawInputString.substring(this.firstString.length,this.firstString.length+1);
    tempString = temporarySecondPart.split("=");
    this.secondString = tempString[0].split("");
    this.firstLetterSecondNUmber = this.secondString[0];
    this.result = tempString[1].split("");
    this.firstLetterResult = this.result[0];


}
```

Comment: And what is "the problem" ?

Comment: it doesn't split the string when I try to split it by "^".

Comment: Why use `split("")` to split the string into 1-letter elements, when `toCharArray()` will basically do the same, faster? --- Since `s` is nothing but 1-letter values, how would you ever expect it to match `"sqrt"`?

Comment: @Andreas you right about the sqrt thing, didn't think of it, and now I see why it doesn't work for sqrt. But still have no idea why it doesn't work for "^"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`split` is using regular expression (regex) as argument. Some characters have [special meaning](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) in regex (we call them metacharacters) and `^` is one of them. It usually represent start of string, or can be used to create negative character set like `[^a-z]` will represent any character which is not in range `a` and `z`.

If you want to change `^` into simple literal you need to escape it like

`split("\\^")`

but safer way would be allowing regex to do escaping for you. To do so use

`split(Pattern.quote("^"))`

or in your case

`split(Pattern.quote(operator))`.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing some weird jumping through hoops in that code.

`findOperator()` splits `rawInputString` into 1-character strings, then searches for the first `+`, `*`, `-`, `/`, or `^` (ignoring the non-working `sqrt`) and assigns it to `this.operator` as a regex.

You then split `rawInputString` using that regex. Why?
You just found it in `findOperator()`, so you know exactly where it is.

Then you begin splitting, and splitting, and splitting...

All that, when all you want to do is parse a string `a op b = c`?
And you seem to want to save it all in fields:

```
firstString    a as a String[] of 1-character
operator       op
secondString   b as a String[] of 1-character
result         c as a String[] of 1-character

firstLetterFirstNumber   First 1-character string in firstString
firstLetterSecondNUmber  First 1-character string in secondString
firstLetterResult        First 1-character string in result
```

And no error handling whatsoever, so you get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, instead of some meaningful error.

Just use **one** regular expression, and all your values are ready for you.
And using `toCharArray()` will give you the 1-character values as a `char[]`.

```
String rawInputString = "3√343=7";

String regex = "(.+?)([-+*/^√])(.+?)=(.+)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(rawInputString);
if (! m.matches())
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad input: " + rawInputString);

char[] firstString  = m.group(1).toCharArray();
String operator     = m.group(2);
char[] secondString = m.group(3).toCharArray();
char[] result       = m.group(4).toCharArray();

char firstLetterFirstNumber  = firstString[0];
char firstLetterSecondNUmber = secondString[0];
char firstLetterResult       = result[0];

System.out.println("firstString  = " + Arrays.toString(firstString));
System.out.println("operator     = " + operator);
System.out.println("secondString = " + Arrays.toString(secondString));
System.out.println("result       = " + Arrays.toString(result));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
firstString  = [3]
operator     = √
secondString = [3, 4, 3]
result       = [7]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this regex out

```
String abc = "a+b-c*d^f";
String reg = "((?<=[<=|>=|==|\\+|\\*|\\-|<|>|/|=|\\^])|(?=[<=|>=|==|\\+|\\*|\\-|<|>|/|=|\\^]))";

    String [] arr = abc.split(reg); //split your String according to Expression
    for(String obj : arr)
    System.out.println(obj);
```

Your Output will be like that

```
a
+
b
-
c
*
d
^
f
```

> Note :- Your Complete Mathematical expression will be split into an array of String just by finding any mathematical expression in row

Comment: Are you sure you need these `[` and `]`? Same question about first and last `(` `)` :)

Comment: Hint: `[<=|>=]` doesn't do/represent what you think it does.

Comment: i am just writting a `regex` for hint.  you can write your own as per your need. It is advisible to add or remove expression as per your need. @Pshemo Thank you

Comment: Problem is that your hints contain errors. Regex written as something like `[<=|>=]` represents character class which can match only *single character* which is either: `<` or `=` or `|` or `>`, not `<=` or `>=` expressions. Also your solution escapes `+` and `*` placed inside `[...]` character class where they have no special meaning so escaping them is redundant and can cause confusion. But your expression would be correct if you would simply remove `[` and `]`.